# checkbox event onclick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a check box and 3 textboxes, what i want is to disable all 3 textboxes when check box is checked. For that i have done this code but not working.

```
<tr>
<td><?php echo "Modify Default Package Dimensions:"; ?></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="Modify_Default_Dimensions" value="1" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('hide_textbox').disabled=this.checked;"></td>
</tr>

<td><?php echo "Depth"; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" class="hide_textbox" name="dhl_product_depth" value="<?php echo $product_depth ?>" /> cm</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo "Width"; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" class="hide_textbox" name="dhl_product_width" value="<?php echo $product_width ?>" /> cm</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><?php echo "Height"; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" class="hide_textbox" name="dhl_product_height" value="<?php echo $product_height ?>" /> cm</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Try the `setAttribute()` function in javascript, for example see this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: @C0dekid.php whats wrong with mine? and why its not working?

Comment: You used the `this` property, but that only handles the current object/input. And because there are three inputs with the same class you can't directly change this all

Comment: @C0dekid.php — No, the use of `this` is correct. It is trying to read the value from *one* checkbox (which it is doing correctly) and copy it to three others (which is where the problem is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a node list (something like an array but without the methods) and you have to loop through the array to modify each member with that specified class.

For readability, modify your checkbox to call a function when clicked:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Modify_Default_Dimensions" value="1" onclick="checkboxChecked(this);"></td>
```

And define the function:

```
function checkboxChecked(clickedBox) {
    var hide_textbox = document.getElementsByClassName('hide_textbox');
    for(var i = 0; i < hide_textbox.length; i++) {
        hide_textbox[i].disabled = clickedBox.checked;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: If you want your textboxes disabled by default and checking the checkbox will enable them, firstly add this to disable all text box on page load:

```
var textboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('hide_textbox');
for(var b = 0; b < textboxes.length; b++) {
    textboxes[b].disabled = true;
}
```

And then you can modify your function (note that i don't define `hide_textbox` this time).

```
function checkboxChecked(clickedBox) {
    for(var i = 0; i < textboxes.length; i++) {
        textboxes[i].disabled = !clickedBox.checked; // if checked, this will enable it
    }
}
```

Comment: "returns an array" — No, it returns a live node list. That is array-like, but not an array.

Comment: @Quentin Oh, I always thought it was just an array of elements, thanks for the info

Comment: @chris97ong one more thing pls what if i want my textboxes disabled by default and on checked checkbox i want to enable them and so on

Comment: @chris97ong the disable part by default didnt work it was enabled and on checked checkbox they got disabled

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan Hmm im not sure why it wouldn't work, check for syntax errors in your code?

Comment: @chris97ong can u pls share a fiddle demo showing what i want i.e by default textboxes disabled and checkbox unchecked and when checking they should get enabled